# React router working fine on localhost but does not redirect me properly on netlify?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, netlify

My App is working perfectly on `http://localhost:3000/` but when I try to run it on Netlify (`https://famous-swan-6a778d.netlify.app/`) the homepage loads correctly, but when I try to go to some other page it shows the `Page Not Found` error.

My routing is set up as:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import EncryptedMessage from "./components/EncryptedMessage";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
        <Route
          path="/messages/:uniqueId"
          element={<EncryptedMessage />}
        ></Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `/` is working perfectly, but when I try to go to say `https://famous-swan-6a778d.netlify.app/messages/123/` , it throws an error but if I go to `http://localhost:3000/messages/123/` , it's working fine.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the [CRA deployment docs for Netlify](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify) to see what you need to configure on the server to correctly route page requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that strict mode was causing this problem. You can disable it in your index.js file.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent PAGE NOT FOUND error from netlify app:-

Make a file inside public named as _redirects.
Inside it write a line of code

```
/*    /index.html    200
```